# Langinfo.h in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, localization, locale

How can I include into my Visual Studio 2010 C-project langinfo.h. I've tried
`#include <langinfo.h>`, but it seems there is no such header file in the VS 2010 environment. I need to get the starting weekday for the locale, but I now the way only using this library.
So, the question is how to solve my problem: how to include langinfo.h, or how to get the current locale starting weekday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should use GetLocaleInfoEx() function.
For example, to get the starting day of a week these calls might be used:

```
# if defined(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA) && WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA && defined(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT)
    GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IFIRSTDAYOFWEEK, wsDay, 4)
# else
    GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IFIRSTDAYOFWEEK, wsDay, 4)
# endif
```

More info about this function can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example program `first_weekday.c`, which gets the first day of the week. Furthermore, values and sizes of used variables are printed.
`GetLocalInfoEx()` stores the first day of the week in the variable `week_1stday`.
However, on Windows we have: `0:Monday, ... 6:Sunday` (see: [LOCALE_IFIRSTDAYOFWEEK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/locale-ifirstdayofweek)).
Therefore a calculation is included here, in order to get `0:Sunday, 1:Monday, ...`
The number for the first day of the week is stored then in `first_weekday`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(
    )
{
    int       ret;
    int       first_weekday;
    DWORD     week_1stday;

    ret = GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT,
                          LOCALE_IFIRSTDAYOFWEEK | LOCALE_RETURN_NUMBER,
                          (LPWSTR) & week_1stday,
                          sizeof(week_1stday) / sizeof(WCHAR));
    /* 0:Monday, ..., 6:Sunday. */
    /* We need 1 for Monday, 0 for Sunday. */
    first_weekday = (week_1stday + 1) % 7;
    printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
    printf("sizeof(ret) = %Iu\n", sizeof(ret));
    printf("sizeof(week_1stday) = %Iu\n", sizeof(week_1stday));
    printf("sizeof(WCHAR) = %Iu\n", sizeof(WCHAR));
    printf("week_1stday = %lu\n", week_1stday);
    printf("first_weekday = %d\n", first_weekday);
    return 0;
}
```

See also:
[GetLocaleInfoEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoex)
[LOCALE_IFIRSTDAYOFWEEK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/locale-ifirstdayofweek)