# Using LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT system constant in vba

Tags: excel, winapi, vba

### **Questions**

- Can I use the `LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT` system constant in VBA, or do I need to use the `GetUserDefaultLocaleName()` function instead?
- If I can use `LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT` system constant, how do I obtain its value?

### **Background**

I use vba to convert the system List Separator value from `,` to `|`, restart Excel, use vba to make a needed csv with the `|` separator, then restore the List Separator value to default and close Excel.

Sometimes the list separator does not switch as expected, so now I am [adapting the method found here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/get-list-separator-character-with-vba.2218762/#post-7042126)
to develop a safeguard that checks the current value to make sure it is `|`.

Microsoft currently recommends  [that we use the more current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103(v=vs.85).aspx) `GetLocaleInfoEx()` instead of `GetLocaleInfo()` for interoperability purposes.

I'm having a hard time obtaining the value of the `LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT` system constant in VBA that the documentation mentions. Here's the relevant snippet of what I have so far:

```
Private Const LOCALE_SLIST = &HC
Private Const LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 85
'Private Const LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT <-- stuck here, it wants me to declare it = to something, but I want the system value

'Get Locale Info
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfoEx _
Lib "kernel32" ( _
ByVal lpLocaleName As String, _
ByVal LCType As Long, _
ByVal lpLCData As String, _
ByVal cchData As Long) As Long


Sub SubName()

    Dim lpLCData As String

        Long1 = GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SLIST, lpLCData, 0)
```

Can you please help me figure out how to obtain the system constant for 
`LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT` so I can use this function in VBA similarly to the `C` example found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674047/4691433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have ready access to a copy of winnls.h but if I recall, it should just be NULL.

That said, keep in mind that the calling convention you're using will return the size of the buffer (in lpLCData) that you need to pass to [GetLocaleInfoEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the given parameters. For functions with this calling convention, I'd get into the habit of always checking for buffer size first, sizing your own string buffer, and then making the actual call with the returned buffer size. Also note that using [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can make debugging API calls from *much* easier.  Give this a shot:

```
Private Const LOCALE_SLIST = &HC
Private Const LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT = vbNullString

Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfoEx Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal lpLocaleName As String, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, _
    ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Sub Example()

    Dim lpLCData As String
    Dim bufferSize As Long

    'Get return buffer size.
    retVal = GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SLIST, lpLCData, 0)
    'GetLocaleInfoEx returns 0 on failure.
    If retVal <> 0 Then
        'Use that value to size your buffer...
        lpLCData = String(retVal, Chr$(0))
        '...and pass the appropriate buffer/size parameters.
        If GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SLIST, lpLCData, retVal) <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print lpLCData
        Else
            Debug.Print GetLastError
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print GetLastError
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a noob moment - I had seen that null might work here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373815(v=vs.85).aspx but I gracefully put `= null` next to my commented out line in the declaration instead of `= vbnullstring` or `= ""`. Thanks for helping me figure it out, and great answer!